# Combining letter vector with number vector matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, concatenation

I wish to combine a vector of letters

```
 AssetList(1,2:end)

ans = 

    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'    'e'
```

with a vector of numbers

```
x

x =

    0.3857
    0.2143
    0.0000
         0
    0.4000
```

to create a table where a=0.3857 etc but I get errors no matter what I try. For example:

```
y=cat(2,alldata(1,2:end)',x)
```

> *Error using cat
>       Dimensions of matrices being concatenated
>       are not consistent.*

Comment: Note that you will not get a meaningfull result by concatenating characters and numbers. If you have a vector or matrix it either needs to be all numbers or all characters, not a combination. I suppose you may want a cell array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want, perhaps something like this:

```
x = 'a':'e'
y = 11:15
C = cell(5,2)
for t = 1:5
   C{t,1}=x(t)
   C{t,2}=y(t)
end
```

It can of course be vectorized, but I find this solution easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Standard MATLAB arrays are only able to cope with one data type, e.g. either chars or doubles. If you want to combine multiple types of data, you will need to employ structs or cells, as Dennis Jaheruddin has done in his answer.

See attached an example on how to put this into an array of structs:

```
for n=1:5
    y(n).character = AssetList(1,n+1)
    y(n).number = x(n)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach almost works. You only need to transform `x` into a cell array (with [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)) before using `cat`:

```
y = cat(2, alldata(1,2:end).', mat2cell(x, ones(1,numel(x))));
```